# Is there any method to set a name for json objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Actually, I am having one json object like this,

```
let json_data = {"name":"john", "age":"19" };
```

Is there any way to assign some name to that json object (am i clear?) like below,

```
"employee" : {"name":"john", "age":"19" };
```

Currently I am assigning it in manually like ,

```
let json_data = {"name":"john", "age":"19" };
let new_data = '"employee" : '+json_data;
```

which I am thinking its not good practice to do so. Any help on this will be grateful.

Why i need this  ? Actually I am creating multiple different json objects based on the inputs i am getting from the form. my json objects results will be like,

```
{"name":"john", "age":"19" }
{"college":"abc", "degree":"PHD"}
[{ "country" : "india", "mobile" : "1234567890"}]
```

I need to assign some names to each json objects and pass it to API, there they will fetch the details by using the names which i set.

Comment: Try `let new_data = {"employee" : json_data };`  A JSON structure is a string of text as what you have done is a simple javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let json_data = {"name":"john", "age":"19" };

let body= {
 "employee" : json_data 
};
console.log('employee', body.employee)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i need exactly like "employee" : {"name":"john", "age":"19" };, means without braces starting and ending

Comment: you can directly access this like `body.employee` .

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object with key as `employee` and value as `json_data` and then get the assigned property name using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) method:

```js
let json_data = {"name":"john", "age":"19" };
let new_data = { employee: json_data }

console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new_data)[0] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to reassign the value of `json_data`.

```
let json_data = { "name": "john", "age": "19" }

json_data = { "employee": { ...json_data } }
```

Essentially you'd be re-making your variable, starting with the new `employee` parent property, and then taking the original object and "copying" its properties as children (that's the `{ ...json_data }` part).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

> [This](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) page has sufficient info to learn what JSON is, please
>   carefully go through it.

Now your question you want to assign a name to the object. There is only one way to do it, wrapping it into another object and then assigning name(by the way it is called a KEY) for the object

```
{"employee" : {"name":"john", "age":"19" }}
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i need exactly like "employee" : {"name":"john", "age":"19" };, means without braces starting and ending

Comment: I am unable to think of the use case, However by doing so, whatever the structure be it won't be a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

**Look like you are looking for better json object**

`"employee" : {"name":"john", "age":"19" };` is not valid json. If you really want u can use string.

```
const str = `"employee" : ${JSON.stringify(user)}`
console.log(str)
```

```js
const user = {"name":"john", "age":"19" }
const college = {"college":"abc", "degree":"PHD"}
const locations = [{ "country" : "india", "mobile" : "1234567890"}]

const info = {
  ...user,
  ...college,
  ...locations[0]
}
console.log(info)

const str = `"employee" : ${JSON.stringify(user)}`
console.log(str)
```